# how to change the border size(thickness) of checkbox in android kotlin?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to make a **checkbox** smaller and change the size of border

I have tried playing around with layout in XML and `.width()`or `.height` in Kotlin. Neither does anything to change the size of it. I went to the tutorial that was recommended to others that asked these questions, but I did not understand what he did.
 Any suggestions?

**mycheckbox.xml**

```
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
```

```
  android:id="@+id/stSafeCheck"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox" />
```

**my_checkbox.xml**

```
<item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background"/>

<item

        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background"/>
```

**checkbox_off_background**

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
                android:width="25dp"
                android:height="25dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background" />
```

**checkbox_on_background.xml**

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
                android:width="25dp"
                android:height="25dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background" />
```

Comment: Hi! Please share your XML layout file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<CheckBox

    android:scaleX="0.70"
    android:scaleY="0.70"
 ...
/>
```

Try this, above API level 11

Comment: the thickness you can not change but you can set drawable or you can make custom checkbox

Answer (score 0):

try using android:scaleX &  android:scaleY.

Thanks,
Rhen

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the thickness I guess but you can set image/drawable for checkbox. Create or design drawable as your required border thickness and **set it as button of checkbox**.

```
<CheckBox 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="checkbox" 
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_design" />
```

For better example [visit here](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html)

Comment: please accept and upvote my answer if it works. :) you can upvote my answer.